# Does ASP.NET's BlogEngine.Net Stack Up to Wordpress?

Tags: .net, wordpress, blogs, blogengine.net

I'm somewhat familiar with Wordpress and I've used it a little. There is a huge community with tons of plugins and themes etc.  Does the BlogEngine.Net compare favorably?  Is there another .NET CMS that you would recommend?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compared to WordPress, BlogEngine.NET is relatively immature and has a much smaller community. That's not to say BlogEngine isn't good on its own merits, but it's definitely more niche where WordPress is mainstream.

As far as .NET **CMS** solutions, and not just blogging platforms, [N2](http://n2cms.com/) and [Graffiti](http://graffiticms.com/) are both very well-regarded and seem to be widely adopted. They are also both geared towards more flexible CMS than simply blogs, although have blog-like functionality baked in. Of course, N2 is open source and Graffiti is a paid product (albeit quite inexpensive), but both do quite well.

Comment: And some of the Microsoft team have been working on Oxite which is a CMS/Blogging Platform. Currently still in beta, but will soon be in beta.... apparently....maybe :)

Comment: I am not impressed with Oxite so far. It looks like that has been rolled into Orchard, so we'll see if they turn it around.

Comment: for what it's worth, Graffiti is now open source, http://telligent.com/company/news/b/teamblog/archive/2009/12/11/graffiti-cms-is-now-open-source.aspx, and can be downloaded from CodePlex, http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 for N2 - it's a great CMS engine, especially with the MVC integration - last time I looked (about a year ago I admit), I found that Graffiti was still too blog focused for my needs, it seemed to be "A blog with some other pages" rather than a CMS, but then I work with MCMS, MOSS, etc for a living ;)

Comment: The new NuGet site uses Orchard.NET, which just put out their 1.0 release.  http://orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 6):

I have no experience with BlogEngine.Net, but to answer your question about any other alternatives, we're using [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com) which is a .Net based CMS, and is highly customizable.
In our experience, it has some performance issues for very large sites, but we're still by and large happy with it.

Comment: Gosh I hate downvotes without comments! Is this really a bad answer?

Comment: am really not sure why this was down voted.This is a reasonable answer and I found it useful.I just up voted your answer Scott

Comment: The new SiteFinity 5.0 has MVC and classic ASP.NET.  Sorry, but most of the open source CMS and blog software leaves a lot to be desired. Sitefinity is easy to use from the content creation level and with some basic .NET skills you can customize it easily.  It leverages .NET instead of reinventing the wheel unlike Orchard and some of the other open source solutions.  If you're planning on using it for non-profit work, it's free.  I think most people would rather work with an easily customizable closed system than an open source one that's hard to understand and customize.  That's my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress is very slick.  It's mature, has ton's of templates and plugins and the administrative tool is fantastic.  Installation is simple -- even on IIS7/PHP.

I am primarily a .Net programmer, though I can work with PHP as well (I just don't care for it.)  So, I'd like to say that BlogEngine.Net could "stack up", but I think from an operational perspective, Wordpress is still the leader.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but I've heard good things about [dasBlog](http://dasblog.codeplex.com/) which is an open source .NET blog similar to WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what matters to you.  Give BlogEngine.net a try and give Wordpress a try.  This isn't our blog it's yours.  I usually find using it for about 1-3 weeks messing with features and just what feels right for me works the best.

Answer (score 1):

[Atomsite](http://atomsite.net/) is another option, the admin interface looks very similar to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Wordpress, but it does strike me that Wordpress is a little bit more than just a blog engine, more of a complete document management solution.

So for me personally, I found that "less is more" I quite like the simplicity of BlogEngine.

Answer (score 0):

We're using BlogEngine.Net.  Yes it is less mature, and sometimes, the community is a bit quiet on the threads.  It is well written however and uses ASP.Net webforms.  We've integrated it with our Profile membership on our site which works well.

However, one thing to note - it was never designed to work on web farms or clouds.  There are a few workarounds in the forums to help if you are having problems here.... but it is not ideal.

Editors can't have their own blogs either.  It has been the most asked feature for quite awhile.  Again, a few users have contributed solutions to implement this feature, but it will break your upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

There are also issues integrating Blogengine into a pre-existing CMS and issues with having multiple blogs on the same server. There are definitely hacks that you can implement to do both of these, but we decided it wasn't worth the energy and just used wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I run a single user blog and a .Net developer.  After checking out BlogEngine.Net and dasblog tonight I will be moving from WordPress to BlogEngine.Net.  (Nothing really bad to say about Wordpress I just want to be running on a .Net platform)

Answer (score 0):

I've used both extensively (at work and home). BlogEngine to Wordpress is like Windows 98 to Mac OSX. Yes they both do the same basic things but using one leaves you with a sense of inspiration/calm (Wordpress) while using the other (BlogEngine) leaves you uninspired and frustrated. That may be largely due to the lopsided size of the corresponding communities of each platform - but it is what it is. In any case I am forced to use BlogEngine at work - but decided to stick with Wordpress for my home/personal blog.

I know it'll never happy but man I wish there was a .NET version of Wordpress!